# jsTree Search: show subnodes

Tags: jstree

How can I make jsTree hide non-matching elements, but still display the subnodes of matched elements?

As far as I know there are only two possibilities, that are both not suited for this case. You can either make jsTree hide no element at all by setting

```
show_only_matches: false
```

Or you can make it hide all non-matched elements by setting

```
 show_only_matches: true
```

But this option also hides the subnodes of matched nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution, though it doesn't look really nice, but it works.
Just pass a the found elements the the *enableSubtree()*-function, and it will show the nodes and take care of the correct appearance (i.e. that the dotted lines are shown and hidden correctly).

```
enableSubtree = function(elem) {
  elem.siblings("ul:first").find("li").show();
  return correctNode(elem.siblings("ul:first"));
};

correctNode = function(elem) {
  var child, children, last, _j, _len1, _results;
  last = elem.children("li").eq(-1);
  last.addClass("jstree-last");
  children = elem.children("li");
  console.log(children);
  _results = [];
  for (_j = 0, _len1 = children.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
    child = children[_j];
    _results.push(correctNode($(child).children("ul:first")));
  }
  return _results;
};
```

A call of this function could look like this:

```
enableSubtree($(".jstree-search"))
```

since all found nodes receive the CSS class *.jstree-search*.

Answer (score 2):

```
"search" : {
   "show_only_matches"          : true,
   "show_only_matches_children" : true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to overload "search.jstree" with something like it ? (with show_only_matches==false)

```
 $("#mytreecontainerid").bind("search.jstree", function (e, data) {
   // close the whole tree if a search text in set
   if (data.rslt.str.length>0) $("#mytreecontainerid").jstree('close_all');

   // open the found nodes' parent
   for (var i = 0 ; i<data.rslt.nodes.length ; i++) {
     data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.nodes[i]).open_node(this, false);
     /* here you can do any additional effect to your node */
   }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
The problem is that my tree is really long, > 2 pages on the screen. Therefore displaying the non-matched nodes isn't really an alternative - even if they are all closed. Instead, they have to be hidden completely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code I did for the filtering.

```
    filterTree = function (elem) {
        $('li a', elem).not(".jstree-search").parent().css('display', 'none');
        $('a.jstree-search', elem).parentsUntil(elem, 'li').css('display', 'block');
    };
```

and call it with the jstree instance..

```
    filterTree($treeVar);
```

It might not be an optimal solution, but it works perfectly :)